# How do IIS AppPool Users get created and where are they stored?

Tags: windows, iis, user-management

When viewing the group "IIS_IUSRS", there are users such as:

- IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool
- IIS APPPOOL\MySite1
- IIS APPPOOL\MySite2

When looking for the user in the users view, there are now users with the prefix "IIS APPPOOL\".

What is this prefix?
How are these users generated?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities